# Expressions logically equivalent to "such that"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The question arises from the rewording of some theorems, by example continuity of a function $f$, we have that

$$f\text{ is continuous at }c\iff (\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0:|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon)\tag{1}$$

then I think I can reword this as

$$f\text{ is continuous at }c\iff ((|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon)\implies (\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0))$$

The last statement seem strange to read but the last implication seems logically equivalent to $(1)$. Anyway this is just an experiment.

My question is, there is some expression logically equivalent to "such that" that can be written with basic logical operators as $\lor$, $\land$, $\lnot$, $\iff$ and $\implies$? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that; that's not how quantifiers (or conditionals) work.

"$\forall \epsilon>0$" just means, "For all $\epsilon>0$." It doesn't *assert* anything - e.g. it doesn't make sense to say ""$\forall \epsilon>0$" is false". Similarly with "$\exists \delta>0$."

So an expression of the form "...$\implies (\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0)$" is meaningless: "$\implies$" connects two *sentences*.

The issues go further than this: quantifiers *bind variables*. The expression "$\forall x(x>5)$" is a sentence; the expression "$x>5$" is not, and the expression "$(x>5)\implies (\forall x)$" is *really* not.

Comment: Then the meaning of "such that" is irreducible to other logic operators, right?

Comment: @Masacroso I don't understand what you're asking. "Such that" is *implicit* in how quantifiers work - e.g. "$\exists x(P(x))$" *means* "There exists an $x$ such that $P(x)$." So I *think* the answer to your comment is "no?" But I don't really understand what you mean by "irreducible to other logic operators" . . .

Comment: Oh, Ok, I understand... "such that" is implicit to quantifiers, silly me.

Comment: (An anecdote: I was not too long ago giving a seminar talk with a certain older logician in the audience. He frequently fidgeted when I wrote, and I had no idea why. After the talk, someone came up to me and asked a question, and in the process of answering I wrote "$\exists x$ s.t." on the board; the older logician he got up and erased the "s.t." and gave me a short historical lecture on how that was redundant. :P)

Answer (score 1):

**Abstractions.** The closest thing to "such that" is a lambda operator or an abstraction. You can actually define a quantifier using an abstraction operator and property of attributes being universal or non-empty. See details in Fitch's "Symbolic Logic: An Introduction". Lambda operator can be defined using combinators. See details in Fitch's "Elements of Combinatory Logic"

**Examples.**

1. *Abstraction or lambda operator.* Suppose you have statement "sky is blue and transparent" you can also can paraphrase this like "sky has properties of being blue and transparent", you can paraphrase this property like "(x\x is blue and transparent)". Now you can say that "sky is blue and transparent" is logically equivalent to "(x\x is blue and transparent)""sky". Here used convention that we write property first and argument second. So we can write "(x\ x is red)""ball", this is logically equivalent to "ball is red".
2. *Universal properties.* Lets consider statement "(x\x=x)", that is property of being equal to itself. This property has property of being universal. We can write this like "A(x\x=x)".
3. *Existential properties.* Lets consider property of being equal to five "(x\x=5)". This property has property of being non-empty, that is of having some objects that has this property. We can write this like "E(x\x=5)".
4. *Quantifiers in terms of abstraction and universal or existential attributes.*"A(x\x=x)" is equivalent to $\forall x x=x$. "E(x\x=5)" is equivalent to $\exists x x=5$. More generally "A(x\P(x))" is equivalent with $\forall x P(x)$. "E(x\Q(x))" is equivalent to $\exists x Q(x)$.
5. *Abstraction or lambda operator in terms of combinators.* We have analyzed quantifiers by dividing them into universal or non-empty attributes and abstraction operator. We can also analyze abstraction operator too. It can be shown that every (x\ $\phi(x)$) where $\phi(x)$ is some logical expression can be expressed using this expression and operators called combinators. Basically, suppose you have a function of several variables. Using combinators you can obtain same function but only variable places are changed or some arguments are missing or doubbled. There are several combinators: I, C, K, T, W.

I P(x,y,z) is equivalent P(x,y,z).

C P(x,y,z) is equivalent to P(x,z,y).

K P(x,y,z) is equivalent to P(x,z).

T P(x,y,z) is equivalent to P(y,x,z).

W P(x,y,z) is equivalent to P(x,y,y,z).

By applying this operators to formula you can compute abstraction of it.

6. Be cautious combinatory logic is incompatible with all the rules of classical logic.

**Descriptions.**
Another thing that is very similar to "such that" is definite description operator $℩$. I found following information in Anderson's and Johnstone's book "Natural Deduction".

**Examples.**

1. Imagine you have a attribute of variable (we call it predicate) $\psi(x)$. It may be $x^2=0$. Expression $℩x(\psi(x))$ denotes "the x that has property $\psi(x)$". So $℩x(x^2=0)$ is equal to 0.
2. $℩$ operator can be expressed in terms of predicate logic.
   Expression $n=℩\alpha(\psi(\alpha))$ is equivalent to
   $\exists \alpha [\forall \beta [\psi(\beta)\equiv(\alpha=\beta)]\land(\alpha=n)]$.
3. Expression $\phi[℩\alpha(\psi(\alpha))]$ is equivalent to  $\exists \alpha [\forall \beta [\psi(\beta)\equiv(\alpha=\beta)]\land(\phi(\alpha)]$.
4. Lets us assume we have some function $f(x)$. We want to express statement "the x such that f(x) is continuous". We may want to have this expression to substitute it then in some other formula.
   This expression can be written $℩x(\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=f(c))$
5. Be cautious. For descriptions identity relation may not be reflexive, symmetric or transitive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1747377)

Comment: I find your comment strange, may be my English was not clear enough. Question is:"My question is, there is some expression logically equivalent to "such that" that can be written with basic logical operators as ∨, ∧, ¬, ⟺ and ⟹?" My answer is "such that" can be thought as abstraction operator, which can be expressed using I, K, C, T, W operators. In my answer I tried to show these concepts on simple examples.

Comment: The OP of the question makes no reference to combinatory logic. Their question is explicitly about representing 'such that' using operators under classical logic. This answer seems less like it addresses the question and more like a short description of the basics of combinatory logic.

Comment: I understood "logical operators as..." as "logical operators as ... or something similar to logical operators ....". I find combinators similar to logical operators. Frequently when people are asking questions they not only don't know something, but they don't know that they don't know. Most of the question I ask my self are answered by correcting the question. So I think that broader answer will be better. So I thought that broader answer will be "how can I analyze 'such as' ". From my perspective it seemed evident that author of the question wants to formalize and analyze "such that".